# How do I fix transpose formula so that I don't have to type again and again

Tags: excel

I have this data and I am trying to arrange them according to some format I have given,so what I am doing basically is selecting four names transposing them but names are in thousands.

What I have done so far is selecting 4 names copying and pasting them. ctr + alt + v then E then enter. 2nd way I tried this by using this formula of transpose and selecting 4 names it transpose them. But how do I transpose 4 names as fast possible.Any thoughts on this ?
[image]

[image]

Comment: `=Transpose(OFFSET(C1:C4, (ROW()-1)*4,0))`

Comment: @TimWilliams It showing me #value! sir

Comment: @TimWilliams See the screenshot

Comment: Did you enter the formula using Ctrl+Shift+Enter?

Comment: @TimWilliams yes sir

Comment: @TimWilliams I selected 4 columns and pasted formula .

Comment: Give me a minute....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this (entered in row1 and filled down):

```
=TRANSPOSE(OFFSET($C$1:$C$4,4*(SUM(ROW())-1),0))
```

...and this explains why my initial suggestion failed:

https://superuser.com/questions/525537/excel-offset-function-returns-value-error-when-combined-with-row-function